# PyGithub and Python 3.6

Tags: python, github, pygithub

I have the following script that grabs a repository from Github using PYGitHub

```
import logging
import getpass
import os
from github import Github, Repository as Repository, UnknownObjectException


GITHUB_URL = 'https://github.firstrepublic.com/api/v3'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logging.debug('validating GH token')
    simpleuser = getpass.getuser().replace('adm_','')
    os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~' + getpass.getuser()) + '/.ssh/github-' + simpleuser + '.token'))
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~' + getpass.getuser()) + '/.ssh/github-' + simpleuser + '.token'), 'r') as token_file:
            github_token = token_file.read()
    logging.debug(f'Token after file processing: {github_token}')
    logging.debug('initializing github')
    g = Github(base_url=GITHUB_URL, login_or_token=github_token)

    logging.debug("attempting to get repository")
    source_repo = g.get_repo('CLOUD/iam')
```

Works just fine in Python 3.9.1 on my Mac.

In production, we have RHEL7, Python 3.6.8 (can't upgrade it, don't suggest it). This is where it blows up:

```
(virt) user@lmachine: directory$ python3 test3.py -r ORG/repo_name -d
DEBUG:root:validating GH token
DEBUG:root:Token after file processing: <properly_formed_token>
DEBUG:root:initializing github
DEBUG:root:attempting to get repository
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): <domain>:443
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test3.py", line 68, in <module>
source_repo = g.get_repo(args.repo)
File "/home/adm_gciesla/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github/MainClass.py", line 348, in get_repo
"GET", "%s%s" % (url_base, full_name_or_id)
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 319, in requestJsonAndCheck
verb, url, parameters, headers, input, self.__customConnection(url)
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 410, in requestJson
return self.__requestEncode(cnx, verb, url, parameters, headers, input, encode)
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 487, in __requestEncode
cnx, verb, url, requestHeaders, encoded_input
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 513, in __requestRaw
response = cnx.getresponse()
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 116, in getresponse
allow_redirects=False,
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
chunked=chunked,
File "/home/user/virt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1295, in _send_request
self.putheader(hdr, value)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1232, in putheader
raise ValueError('Invalid header value %r' % (values[i],))
ValueError: Invalid header value b'token <properly_formed_token>\n'
```

The script is a stripped down version of a larger application. I've tried rolling back to earlier versions of PyGitHub, that's really all I have control over in prod. Same error regardless. PyGithub's latest release claims Python >=3.6 should work.

I've really run the gamut of debugging. Seems like reading from environment variables can work sometimes, but the script needs to be able to use whatever credentials are available. Passing in the token as an argument is only for running locally.

Hopefully someone out there has seen something similar.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error running your code under Python 3.6.8 on RHEL 7. We would be able to provide better answers if you updated your question to include a value for `GITHUB_TOKEN` that reproduces this error. It doesn't need to be a valid token; you can create one and delete it, or create one and then modify it, as long as the modified version still triggers the same error.

Comment: I edited the question to strip the code down further... It appears to be the file reading code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just figured it out. Apparently, even though there's no newline in the `.token` file, there is one after calling `file.read()`

Changing `github_token = token_file.read()` to `github_token = token_file.read().strip()` fixes the problem.

Comment: I really wish `file.read()` and `file.readlines()` allowed you to pass a boolean to strip whitespace.

Comment: `file.read()` doesn't magically add newlines -- if there's a newline in the data, then there's a newline in the file (which you can probably verify using something like `xxd` or `od` to produce a hex dump of the content).